# LINQ query for fetching data using Entity Framework from multiple tables with Lambda expressions and without Join keyword

Tags: linq, sql-server-2008, asp.net-web-api, lambda, entity-framework-6

I want to fetch details of Employee from three tables based on employeeNumber.

Three Tables :

1. EmployeeDetails (employeeNumber primarykey & userID,designationId Foreignkey)
2. UserDetails (userId primaryKey)
3. Designations (designationId primarykey)

**UserDetails**

```
    public partial class UserDetail
    {
        public UserDetail()
        {
            this.EmployeeDetails = new HashSet<EmployeeDetail>();
        }
        public System.Guid user_id { get; set; }
        public string employee_name { get; set; }
        public string employee_email { get; set; }
        public decimal employee_contactnumber { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeDetail> EmployeeDetails { get; set; }
}
```

**EmployeeDetails**

```
public partial class EmployeeDetail
    {       
        public System.Guid employee_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.Guid> user_id { get; set; }
        public int employee_number { get; set; }          
        public Nullable<int> designation_id { get; set; }           

        public virtual Designation Designation { get; set; }         
        public virtual UserDetail UserDetail { get; set; }
    }
```

**Designations**

```
 public partial class Designation
    {
        public Designation()
        {
            this.EmployeeDetails = new HashSet<EmployeeDetail>();
        }

        public int designation_id { get; set; }
        public string designation_name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> create_date { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<EmployeeDetail> EmployeeDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to add navigation properties to your entity classes if you haven't yet. That would cause EF to inject the join without you having to specify join conditions.

Changed your identifiers to match conventions, otherwise you have to explicitly configure the associations.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public int UserDetailId { get; set; }
    public UserDetail UserDetail { get; set; }
}

public class UserDetail
{
    public int UserDetailId { get; set; }
    public string SomeUserDetailProperty{ get; set; }

    public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

This allows for

```
db.Employees.Select(e => new 
{
    e.EmployeeId,
    e.UserDetail.SomeUserDetailProperty
})
```

Comment: e.UserDetail.SomeUserDetailProperty, here after e.UserDetails. then it is not displaying my tables or properties.

Comment: Of course `SomeUserDetailProperty` is an example for something you might want to select from `UserDetail`. Can you edit your question to include your entity classes?

Comment: I am saying that it is displaying Add, Array, select, etc apart from my tables  . Ok I will edit

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = entities.EmployeeDetails.Select(e => new GetUserInfo {designation= e.Designation,userDetail = e.UserDetail, employeeDetail = e }).Where(e => e.employeeDetail.employee_number == number);
```

This is working fine. Thank you

GetUserInfo class consists of :

```
   public class GetUserInfo{

     public UserDetails userDetail {get;set;}
     public EmployeeDetails employeeDetail {get;set}
     public Designations designation{get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a **view** in your database and fetch data using that view in entityframework